# Making a non-instantaneous change with an @IBAction button in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to change the value of the speech rate property of my AVSpeechUtterance upon clicking a button in my app. I then want this value to carry over when I press the "speak" button.

If that explanation wasn't clear enough imagine this:

There are three buttons: one, two and three.
When the user presses one, the value of a the rate of an utterance changes (The same goes for the two and three).

Then after pushing one of the first three buttons, the user pushes another button that activates an utterance. This utterance will carry over the rate value and apply it to the speech.

Here is the code I have tried but doesn't work:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var minutesLabel: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var secondsField: UITextField!

func speak(sender: AnyObject) {

    let speechUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string:exampleSpeech)

    speechSynthesizer.speakUtterance(speechUtterance)
}

@IBOutlet var result: UILabel!

@IBAction func verySlow(sender: UIButton) {

    let verySlowButtonPressed = true

    let talkingSpeed = 90

    let minutesValue : Double = (minutesLabel.text as NSString!).doubleValue
    let secondsValue = (secondsField.text as NSString!).doubleValue
    let secondsToMinutes = secondsValue / 60
    let compiledTime = Double(minutesValue) + Double(secondsToMinutes)
    let resultingWords = Double(compiledTime) * Double(talkingSpeed)
    let resultCeiling = ceil(resultingWords)

    result.text = "\(String(format: "%.0f", resultCeiling)) words"

    if verySlowButtonPressed {

        speechUtterance.rate = 0.25
        speechUtterance.pitchMultiplier = 0.25
        speechUtterance.volume = 0.75
    }

}


@IBAction func speakButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    speak(exampleSpeech)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `speak` function you are creating a new `AVSpeechUtterance` instance every time it's called. When your `verySlow` function is called, it's setting the `rate`, `pitchMultiplier`, and `volume` on what I'm presuming is a class property called `speechUtterance`.  Since you're creating a new `AVSpeechUtterance` in `speak` each time it's called, those properties that you are setting in `verySlow` are not going to be set on the same instance.

One way to solve this would be to make `rate`, `pitchMultiplier`, and `volume` properties in your class, set *those* in your `verySlow` function, and then set them on `speechUtterance` after you create it in your `speak` function.

Something like:

```
var rate: Float?
var pitchMultiplier: Float?
var volume: Float?

func speak(sender: AnyObject) {

    let speechUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string:exampleSpeech)

    if let rate = self.rate { 
        speechUtterance.rate = rate 
    }
    if let pitchMultiplier = self.pitchMultiplier { 
        speechUtterance.pitchMultiplier = pitchMultiplier 
    }
    if let volume = self.volume { 
        speechUtterance.volume = volume 
    }

    speechSynthesizer.speakUtterance(speechUtterance)
}

@IBAction func verySlow(sender: UIButton) {

    // ... whatever other code you need here ...

    self.rate = 0.25
    self.pitchMultiplier = 0.25
    self.volume = 0.75

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You must be a Java person with your use of "this" haha

Comment: @JoeySmith haha, oops.  I do a lot of javascript in my day job... must have slipped in.  I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but these are the value for speech rate, try using them. I hope it helps.

iOS 9
Very Slow -- 0.42
Slower    -- 0.5
My Normal -- 0.53
Faster    -- 0.56

Value are different for previous versions of iOS, please keep that in mind while implementing the solution.